# Application freezes when 2xclick on the binary but ok if run from a terminal

Tags: freeze, elf, freepascal, openbsd, netbsd

I have a fpc (free pascal) with msegui widgetset application that compiles ok on OpenBSD.
It runs perfectly when launched from terminal.
But if 2xclick on the binary in the window manager, the app launch and freezes directly and 100% of the cpu is used, I have to kill the process.
This also for a simple only form without anything inside.

How to debug this because using gdb, it acts like a terminal and then no problem, no freeze nor perpetual loop.

Does it exist a tool to run before the 2xclick on the binary to analyze what causes that perpetual loop?

For info, this problem occurs also for NetBSD but is ok for FreeBSD, Linux and Windows.